# When a new user is added to a SharePoint Website what happens in background?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user

When a new user is added to a SharePoint Website what happens in background, what are the process that runs, which tables in the DB are updated?

Comment: This process isn't documented in detail. This is because it's not supported to query of modify SharePoint Databases directly. What are you trying to achieve? I'm sure there's an answer without directly going to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we give a user permission to the site collection, or when that user creates/updates/deletes any item within a Site Collection, the user will be added to the Hidden User information List which store information in relevant content database [WSS_Content].[dbo].[UserInfo] table.

There are two timer jobs named User Profile Service Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization and User Profile Service Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization, will update the user profile information in the user profile service application to User information list, through a mapping between the Profile DB and content DB UserInfo table.

More information about User Information List, check the article:

[User Information List in SharePoint All details](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/User-Information-List-in-8b420e8c)

[What is Hidden User Information (Userinfo) List in SharePoint 2010/2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/marj/2016/03/14/what-is-hidden-user-information-userinfo-list-in-sharepoint-20102013-and-how-to-fix-when-it-causes-a-site-collection-to-show-old-user-metadata-properties-in-people-picker-control-or-in-a-person-or/)